# Cannot retrieve repository metadata for repository: epel (rhel 6.6)

Tags: redhat, rhel

Im trying to install linux nrpe agent on one of the test rhel boxes for nagiosxi to monitor and when i run the fullinstall script im getting this following error

```
[root@nrpetest2 linux-nrpe-agent]# ./fullinstall
============================
Nagios Linux Agent Installer
============================

This script will install the Nagios Linux Agent by executing all necessary
sub-scripts.

IMPORTANT: This script should only be used on a clean installed system:

   RedHat Enterprise, CentOS, Fedora, or Oracle
   OpenSUSE or SUSE Enterprise
   Ubuntu or Debian

Do NOT use this on a system running any other distro or that
does not allow additional package installation.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Proceeding with installation...
Running './0-repos'...
Configuring Repos...
Enabling EPEL repo...
Installing EPEL PKG: ./packages/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
warning: ./packages/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
Preparing...                ##################################################
epel-release                ##################################################
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
epel-release RPM installed OK
Repos configured OK
RESULT=0
Running './1-prereqs'...
Installing prerequisites...
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
RESULT=1

===================
INSTALLATION ERROR!
===================
Installation step failed - exiting.
Check for error messages in the install log (install.log).

If you require assistance in resolving the issue, please include install.log
in your communications with Nagios XI technical support.
```

The script that failed was: './1-prereqs'

I have it registered with RedHat network as well and i searched everywhere to find a solution to this error but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the required `epel-release` for nagios to install.
Have your tried doing a `sudo yum install epel-release`?

That would be my biggest guess, according to your line:

> Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again RESULT=1
> The script that failed was: './1-prereqs'

Also, ***check*** to make sure that ***your proxy settings*** allow for a connection to that repository. Sometimes this causes a problem with downloading certain repo data.

So, in short, update your epel-release and make sure that any other pre-requisities have been updated. It probably wouldn't hurt to do: `sudo yum install yum-utils` to make sure that yum-utils is fully up-to-date.

**UPDATE:** From: [Access Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/45815)

1. Verify that Satellite or Proxy Server has a fully-qualified domain name, and CommonName in SSL cert. used by Apache is set to the fully-qualified domain name.
2. Verify that the ssl.conf file is pointing to the correct files.
   `grep ^SSLCert /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`
3. If system points to a proxy, check to make sure that `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date` is configured with **correct http_proxy information.** 
   `httpProxy=http_proxy_fqdn or ip_address:port`
4. Update yum to latest version: `yum update yum`
5. Clean the cache on client system: `rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*`

Comment: when i run yum install epel-release it is still giving the repository metadata error..and same with yum-utils

Comment: @WajahatMakki You more than likely have a proxy setting which is blocking you from getting these repositories

Comment: @WajahatMakki I just added a lot of info, try these updated steps.

Comment: ok i actually got it to work by removing the epel files in /etc/yum.repos.d..thanks anyways!